# keychain error while fetching device id

Tags: ios, spotify

- I am working on a project which requires integration with cocoalibspotify. I have some unit test cases for the classes that import CocoaLibSpotify.h. Those test cases have failed with the following stack trace:

Assertion failure in NSString* base::deviceIdFromKeychain()(), /Users/spotify-buildagent/buildAgent/work/1e0ce8a77adfb2dc/client/base/_apple/_ios/os_ios.mm:287
2013-10-20 11:14:03.505 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Keychain error when fetching device ID, nonrecoverable'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30f0cf53 0x3b2366af 0x30f0ce2d 0x318b41df 0x2d142f 0x2d1a09 0x2ce6db 0x17b1b5 0x1798b3 0x30ed81b9 0x30ed753b 0x30ed5e45 0x30e40ce7 0x30e84803 0x179b1d 0x318efe27 0x3b85dc1d 0x3b85db8f 0x3b85bc90)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

The method at which the exception is thrown is in the SPSession.m class: CFRunLoopRun();

```
+(void)runBackgroundRunloop:(dispatch_block_t)runLoopReadyBlock {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [NSThread currentThread].name = @"com.spotify.CocoaLibSpotify";
        [runloopReadyLock lock];
        libspotify_runloop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
        sleep(1);
        libspotifyThread = [NSThread currentThread];

        // Use a custom, no-op run loop source to keep the loop alive and fast.
        CFRunLoopSourceContext libspotify_source_context;
        memset(&libspotify_source_context, 0, sizeof(CFRunLoopSourceContext));
        libspotify_runloop_source = CFRunLoopSourceCreate(NULL, 0, &libspotify_source_context);
        CFRunLoopAddSource(libspotify_runloop, libspotify_runloop_source, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

        [runloopReadyLock unlockWithCondition:1];
        CFRunLoopRun();

        CFRelease(libspotify_runloop_source);
        CFRelease(libspotify_runloop);
        libspotify_runloop_source = NULL;
        libspotify_runloop = NULL;
        libspotifyThread = nil;
    }
}
```

I have no clue what causes the error or how to fix it. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the latest version of CocoaLibSpotify (2.4.5).

Also, how are the unit tests run? Does your app run correctly? Does CocoaLibSpotify's own unit test suite run? It's worth noting that the Keychain is unaccessible to CocoaLibSpotify before the device has been unlocked.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The unit tests are run under ios7 XCTest Framework. The CocoaLibSpotify's own unit test suite runs correctly. My app runs fine when I manually test it. It just the unit tests failed to run. What do you mean by "the device has been unlocked"? How do I determine if my device has been unlocked or not? Thank you